# Android - How to add TextView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Can someone tell me how to add a TextView at the bottom of the TabbedLayout/List View?

Here is the main Activity, which hosts tab fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChecklistActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Currently, the Tabbed Fragment occupies all space under the Tabbed Widget and contains a ListView and some other TextViews/buttons at the bottom of it.

I want a TextView that is outside the Fragment at the bottom of the main Activity as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to anchor the `view_pager` with your `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChecklistActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myTextView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Or as an alternative, you can use `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChecklistActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/myTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabAppBarLayout" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That does indeed put a TextView at the bottom. However, the fragment is behind it and the fragment doesn't resize to allow for the TextView. So the textview is overlaying the numbers and buttons at the bottom of the fragment. How do we get the fragment to take the textview into account?

Comment: Did you try exactly the same as I have posted? It is basically done with app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges and app:layout_insetEdge, anchoring corresponding views. I have tried this and it works for me...

Comment: Thanks. It was not obvious that you had changed the attributes of the ViewPager. I was focused solely on the TextView. It does seem to be working now!!! Bravo.

Comment: Unless I missed something else, this causes another problem. It pushes the TAB fragment up so that the top of it is hidden and out of view - behind the TabLayout itself.

Comment: So what if you add margin_top to view_pager equal to the TextViews height when it is visible?

Comment: Hi Tiko - not exactly sure what you are asking me to do there. Modify the ViewPager XML to add the following: 'android:layout_marginTop="@+id/bottomTextView"'. If I do that, I get error 'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12'

Comment: I got this layout from the Android Studio template for Tabbed Activity. How would I convert this to not using the CoordinatorLayout? If possible.

Comment: this doesn't work android:layout_marginTop="@+id/bottomTextView, you need to provide the value of margin directly or do this programmatically from your Activity. If you don't need of CoordinatorLayout, you can simply use ConstraintLayout. I can edit the answer and add a solution with ConstraintLayout too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was concerned that removing the CoordinatorLayout would somehow ruin the functionality of the App that I had built up using this design pattern from the Android Template. It appears to work wonderfully and now I can use ConstraintLayout that I am familiar with! Thanks much Tiko!